# update action not working in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

When I am updating my form it is throwing error for field which is unique.

in my model

```
validates :url, presence: true, uniqueness: true, :if => lambda {self.role_id == 2}
```

in my form

```
= f.text_field :url, :class => 'form-control'
```

in my controller

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update(user_params)
    format.html { redirect_to stores_path, notice: 'Store was successfully updated.' }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
  end
end
end
```

Even if I am not doing anything it is giving me error "This url has already been taken". Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: You already have an object with the same URL you are trying to enter now. As in model validations you have said url should be unique the model is throwing an error.

Comment: @AlokSwain You are right.But i am just updating the object and not even changing an alphabet in any fields.How is it throwing error for itself(it's own field value).

Comment: Have you somewhere defined @user as find(... ?

Comment: @techdreams - can you insert the user object and the params sent during update ?

Comment: RubyRacer:  Yes
   
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

Alok: If I catch the params value and insert in update , how can I apply validation wherever required. It might be a security breach

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I meant to paste them in the comments so that I can see it, not in the update action.

Comment: {"url"=>"test", "retailer_group_id"=>"1", "contact_person"=>"test", "website"=>"", "phone_number"=>"", "email"=>"myemail@gmail.com", "first_name"=>"first", "last_name"=>"last", "title"=>"Mr", "mobile"=>"", "role_id"=>"2"}

Comment: and the update params ?

Comment: This is what i get with params while debugging

{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"sutzglfyhke34/3Li02mBOvHF4EHGI//xUjeLmZKRys=", "user"=>{"title"=>"Mr", "contact_person"=>"test", "retailer_group_id"=>"1", "first_name"=>"first", "last_name"=>"last", "phone_number"=>"", "mobile"=>"", "email"=>"myemail@gmail.com", "website"=>"", "url"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Save", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"users", "id"=>"98"}

Comment: can you use `update_columns` instead of `update` to escape validation ..... Please refer this http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns

Comment: Possibly, there are 2 records (created before you added this validation, or created with role_id != 2 ) with the same value in the url field. Whenever you try to save any one of them, it'll fail validation. Just a guess.

Comment: @roob Yes there are entries in user table of users who are child of this object . But I can't remove url field from them it will get very messy and I can not redo things everywhere. What to do in this. Moreover this error is coming even if parent object has no child  and there is no other entry with the same url in it. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this way.

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update(user_params)
    format.html { redirect_to stores_path, notice: 'Store was successfully updated.' }
  else
    incoming_url = User.where("id=? and url=?",@user.id,params[:user][:url])
    if !incoming_url.blank?
      format.html { redirect_to stores_path, notice: 'Store was successfully updated.' }
    end
    format.html { render :edit }
  end
end
end
```